# Can several games start at the same time in one tournament?

Tags: rules, tournaments

In professional tournaments/championships and across sports, can different games be started at the same time?

When or why would the organisers do that?

Comment: What would make you think that this *can't* happen?

Comment: For example FIFA. The matches passed one after another.

Comment: In general, that's to maximize television revenue. As you can see from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_FIFA_World_Cup#Group_A), the last matches in each group at the 2018 World Cup kicked off at the same time (remember to account for local time differences).

Comment: Related: [Why FIFA didn't prevent the potential cheating that may arise when the lasts of group matches are not played simultaneously?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/18686/why-fifa-didnt-prevent-the-potential-cheating-that-may-arise-when-the-lasts-of).

Comment: In most major national football leagues (Premiere League, Bundesliga, La liga, Serie A etc.), in the Champions league, in the Europa League a lot of games do start at the same time. Same for NBA, NHL and many more. So it's a common practice to start several different games at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can they? Yes, unless a particular regulation says otherwise. Will they? It depends on the tournament's needs.

A tournament may start matches at identical times for competitive purposes (teams cannot easily plan to attain a specific result based on corresponding game results elsewhere in the competition) or for scheduling (if a large number of matches must be completed in a short time, having a common timetable across several venues is helpful).

A tournament may start matches at staggered times for management purposes (grounds staff or officials may be necessary to begin, but not required after that; however there are too many matches to only play them consecutively).

A tournament may also start matches consecutively, where one finished before the next. This is primarily due to broadcast requirements (the audience does not have to pick and watch only one or flicker between two games) but in some sports may also be due to venue availability (for example, if there are few games each day they can be spaced reasonably on a single field).

The same tournament may apply any or all of these, as well, depending on the stage they are at. For example, the FIFA World Cup plays the group matches at staggered or consecutive times, although the final group matches are played at identical times, while the knockout matches are played strictly consecutively (even on different days entirely).